# Use a dictionary to find/replace exact terms in a tokenized pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

Using a dictionary, I need to find and replace terms in a pandas series according to the following criteria:

1. dictionary values are replacing dictionary keys wherever they are found in the pandas series (e.g., for example, in 'mastersphd': 'masters phd', the replacement outcome would be 'masters phd' wherever 'mastersphd' occurs)
2. maintain record integrity (i.e., can't use a bag of words approach because I need the unique records to remain intact.)
3. *Only exact matches* should be replaced (for example, if key:value is 'rf': 'random forest', the replacement should not turn 'performance' into 'perandom forestormance'); so regex=True is causing this, obviously)

The Data: term_fixes is the dictionary, and df['job_description'] is the tokenized series of interest

```
term_fixes = {'rf': 'random forest',
              'mastersphd': 'masters phd',
              'curiosity': 'curious',
              'trustworthy': 'ethical',
              'realise': 'realize'}


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'job_description': [['knowledge', 'of', 'algorithm', 'like', 'rf'],
                                            ['must', 'have', 'a', 'mastersphd'],
                                            ['trustworthy', 'and', 'possess', 'curiosity'],
                                            ['we', 'realise', 'performance', 'is', 'key']]})
```

**Note: I have also (unsuccessfully) tried an untokenized data structure, but prefer tokenized since I have more NLP to do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'job_description': ['knowledge of algorithm like rf',
                                            'must have a mastersphd',
                                            'must be trustworthy and possess curiosity',
                                            'we realise performance is critical']})
```

**Desired Outcome (note that the 'rf' in performance is not replaced by 'random forest'):
df['job_description']

```
0    ['knowledge' 'of' 'algorithm' 'like' 'random' 'forest']
1                        ['must' 'have' 'a' 'masters' 'phd']
2          ['must' 'be' 'ethical' 'and' 'possess' 'curious']
3             ['we' 'realize' 'performance' 'is' 'critical']
```

I have tried a number of approaches.
Fail: `df['job_description'].replace(list(term_fixes.keys()), list(term_fixes.values()), regex=False, inplace=True)`

Fail: `df['job_description'].replace(dict(zip(list(term_fixes.keys()), list(term_fixes.values()))), regex=False, inplace=True)`

Fail: `df['job_description'] = df['job_description'].str.replace(term_fixes, regex=False)`

Fail: `df['job_description'] = df['job_description'].str.replace(str(term_fixes.keys()), str(term_fixes.values()), regex=True)`

**The closest I have come is**:

```
df['job_description'] = df_jobs['job_description'].replace(term_fixes, regex=True)
```

However, the regex=True flags on any match (like the 'rf' and 'performance' example above). Changing the flag to regex=False fails to replace anything, unfortunately. I looked in the documentation for another argument I could use, but no luck. Note that this uses the untokenized structure.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "tokenized" version of your `df`.

```
df['job_description'] = df['job_description'].explode().replace(term_fixes).groupby(level=-1).agg(list)

# explode to get single terms per "cell"
# replace to replace the terms in "term_fixes"
# groupby to reverse the previous explode and return to a column of lists

                                   job_description
0  [knowledge, of, algorithm, like, random forest]
1                     [must, have, a, masters phd]
2                 [ethical, and, possess, curious]
3              [we, realize, performance, is, key]
```

If you need the new terms also split on white space, then you can add another intermediate step `.str.split().explode()` before the final `groupby`

```
df['job_description'] = df['job_description'].explode().replace(term_fixes).str.split().explode().groupby(level=-1).agg(list)

                                    job_description
0  [knowledge, of, algorithm, like, random, forest] # random forest is now split
1                     [must, have, a, masters, phd] # masters phd is now split
2                  [ethical, and, possess, curious]
3               [we, realize, performance, is, key]
```

Comment: Runs fast, too - many thanks for this, StevenS!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following to do so with the untokenized data.

```
for k in term_fixes:
    df['job_description'] = (df['job_description'].str.replace(r'(^|(?<= )){}((?= )|$)'.format(k), term_fixes[k]))

print(df)
                             job_description
0  knowledge of algorithm like random forest
1                    must have a masters phd
2        must be ethical and possess curious
3         we realize performance is critical
```

Comment: That's some awesome REGEX - thank you for this! Definitely works on this data sample. However on my larger data set, this approach not replacing many other keys with their associated values (e.g., 'curiosity' is persisting instead of being replaced by 'curious'). Problem must be on my end - although maybe this is replacing only the first instance? Anyway, still looking on my end - thank you!

Comment: Wondering if it's the term_fixes[k] at the end that is causing the terms to be missed. If k is the dictionary key, I think I need the replacing element to be the dictionary value, like m or some such.  Will try.

Comment: The regex will replace all instances of the term in the string. The regex implemented in the solution only takes words that have spaces, the end of string, or the start of string surrounding them!